# denied: requested access to the resource is denied - Docker

Tags: docker

I am new to `Docker` and trying to push the `Docker` image to the hub..giving me the below error.

```
docker container run hellowold
This is v2

docker image tag hellowold:2 prateekaxyz/hellowold:latest

 docker login http://hub.docker.com --username=prateek512
Password:
Login Succeeded

docker push prateekaxyz/hellowold:latest
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/prateekaxyz/hellowold]
93351e248e6e: Preparing
298c3bb2664f: Preparing
73046094a9b8: Preparing
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should login first. suppose you have an account in https://hub.docker.com/
as name/password= prateekaxyz/bar.

before push, you should

```
docker login -u prateekaxyz -p bar
```

after login success, you can push image to docker hub under your namespace

note that your image should begin with your name, eg prateekaxyz/aa:version

Comment: It's worked for me. I already logged in with another Docker Hub account. That is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

1. Build the image with the following format:

```
docker build -t [docker-id]/reponame .
```

which will by default be given "latest" as tag
and then run:

```
docker push [docker-id]/reponame:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first tag your image before pushing

- docker tag firstimage YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/firstimage
  And then you can push it.
- docker push YOUR_DOCKERHUB_NAME/firstimage

reference: https://intellipaat.com/community/207/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker

Answer (score 0):

I have the right answer, the tag name is the key point!!!

if your docker hub username is: "**liushi2n**", then your image should be named like this:

**liushi2n**/centos79py310   1.0        d22a5f384b99   53 minutes ago  1.57GB

Comment: and don't focus on the login,  just use "docker login"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34662826)